# How can I delete everything after the first column in Notepad++?

Tags: script, notepad++, regex

I'm trying to get rid of everything after a column in Notepad++.  Column mode is not an option. Is it possible?

What I have:

```
70.97.110.40    159 ms          [n/a]                   21              
70.97.117.177   134 ms          [n/a]                   21              
70.97.120.10    75 ms           [n/a]                   21              
70.97.122.105   87 ms           www.portless.net        21              
70.97.122.106   89 ms           www.popovetsky.org      21              
70.97.122.107   95 ms           www.psmythe.net         21              
70.97.122.104   98 ms           wasabi.prostructure.com 21              
70.97.122.108   89 ms           crm.prostructure.com    21              
70.97.122.109   87 ms           internal.prostructure.com21
```

What I want:

```
70.97.110.40
70.97.117.177
70.97.120.10
70.97.122.105
70.97.122.106
70.97.122.107
70.97.122.104
70.97.122.108
70.97.122.109
```

Comment: Are the columns tab-separated?

Comment: no theyre white spaces

Comment: One more question: does the data you want to keep ever include a space?

Comment: nope i only need the ips

Comment: Why you want to do that in notepad++? Why column mode is not an option?

Comment: You could use column mode to delete the second column to the EOL, and then use the Trim Trailing and save to get rid of the whitespace.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If the data in the first column never contains a space, you can use a regular expression find and replace to get what you want.

In regular expression mode, search for:

```
^([^ ]*).*
```

And replace with

```
\1
```

What this does:

`^` indicates that any match should start at the beginning of a line.
`([^ ]*)` is any expression that does not contain a space. The match is greedy, so this will match everything up to the first space (or the end of the line, whichever comes first).
`.*` is everything else on the line.

`\1` refers to the part of the match inside the parentheses. That is, the entire line is replaced by just the bit from the first column.

Comment: Nice to know that notepad++ supports regular expressions in search-replace!

Comment: Regex will do the job for you so long as the data never contains a space.  Simpler would be the UNIX 'cut' command but doing UNIX commands under windows is whole 'nother problem. cut is made for this and processes large files quickly, with defined column delimiters or by character-counts.

Comment: This can be done far more simply: replace " .*" (note the leading space) with "" (i.e. nothing) to delete everything after and including the first space.

Comment: @Fraxtil Thanks. You should post that as an answer. You'll get an upvote from me.

Comment: @Excellll alright, done.

Answer (score 99):

Here's a simpler regular expression you can use to achieve the same effect. Replace

```
 .*
```

*(note the leading space)*

with nothing. This will delete everything after and including the first space. This will work as long as your IP addresses are never prefixed with any whitespace (as is the case in your example).

Comment: _Man,_ regex is pure magic. I don't think I'll ever grok it :)

Comment: Make sure that the flag to have . match newlines is off.

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun http://regex101.com/ makes everything 100X easier, http://regex101.com/r/xF2pM4/1 example using that website using the above example

Comment: In case it's potentially a tab instead of a space, you can use `[ \t].*`

Comment: @Cornstalks `\s.*` is shorter. Maybe even use `\s+.*`, to match an arbitrary amount of whitespace, now that we're [coding defensively](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming).

Comment: @Anko: `\s` can match newlines.

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun No, regex is math. It's all based on formal language theory. Try taking a basic course on writing a compiler. Things will start falling into place.

Comment: @jpmc26 as long as you don't say "regex" and "simple" in one sentence :)

Answer (score 40):

If you are using Windows and if you don't mind trailing spaces (you can find/replace them afterwards), use the *Block Select* feature:

1. Press and Hold the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key
2. Using the mouse, select the portion to delete (the entire block of text)
3. Release the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key
4. Delete that block of text
5. Repeat as necessary

Comment: Is that supposed to be the minus "-" key?

Comment: Sorry - I used LT and GT brackets around 'alt' key.  Fixed now.

Comment: You can change it to <kdb>Alt</kbd> and it will format it as a key.

Comment: I've been using Notepad forever....and never knew this feature existed!  1 Bazillion +1!!!!!

Comment: The OP said: "Column mode is not an option"

Comment: You can also remove trailing spaces in Notepad++ using **Edit > Blank Operations > Trim Trailing Space**.

Answer (score 11):

A [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) is quicker, but you can do some really tricky things with macros if it is a more complicated task.

You could record a macro:

1. Cursor on line 1
2. Hit **Start recording**
3. Press key **home**
4. Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while you press key <kbd>Right arrow</kbd> (seven times)
5. Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while you press key <kbd>End</kbd>
6. Press key <kbd>Delete</kbd>
7. Press key <kbd>Down arrow</kbd>
8. Hit <kbd>Stop recording</kbd>

Then play it back:

9. Hit "Run a macro multiple times"
10. Type in the lines of the document minus 1, since the first line is complete.

Answer (score 9):

Place cursor after `70.97.110.40`.

[image: Place cursor]

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and drag the cursor to right and down to select the unwanted part.

[image: Select]

Press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> or <kbd>Delete</kbd>.

[image: Delete]

Comment: All this time using Notepad++ and I never knew it had a "Block Select Mode" like TextPad.

Comment: @Kev: it works the same way in Visual Studio.

Comment: The OP said: "Column mode is not an option"

Comment: @PeterMortensen - re:VS - hell, been using that since 2002 and didn't even know!

Answer (score 8):

Here are a couple of alternative methods to the given answer.

If you data is `fixed width`, you can also use the following [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) in the search:

**Find what:** `^(.{16}).*$`

**Replace with:** `\1`

It is great if the data you want to keep does contain a space, as someone mentioned.  Additionally, again for fixed width data, you can use `Column Mode Editing`. It's a neat little feature that allows you to edit multiple lines of data in the same column location.  See *[Column Mode Editing](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/column-mode-editing.html)*.

It makes mention of arrow keys, but you can also use `Page Up/Down` for a faster method, as well as `End` and `Home` keys. The mouse also works. But you could use this for an ad hoc method of deleting data after a certain point, especially if it is only a few lines. It is also good for copying data, but the way it pastes is a bit odd, so you'd want to get used to that first.

Comment: Better than selecting it and replacing it with itself would be to use a lookbehind like: (?<=^.{13}).* and replace it with nothing.  This will select anything after the first 13 characters.

Answer (score 4):

1. Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>while using  the mouse as a lasso.
2. Select all you want to remove
3. Press <kbd>DELETE</kbd>

Comment: Assuming the first column lines up nicely, like IP addresses, then this is the quickest way.

Comment: The OP said: "Column mode is not an option"

Answer (score 4):

Similar to enthdegree:

1. Place cursor at column 16
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Page Down</kbd>
3. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd>
4. <kbd>Delete</kbd>

If there is a blank line at the end of the file, simply press <kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> prior to #3.

It's not perfect, but it's handy.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a visual way:

- Put cursor at end of an IP address.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Pg Down</kbd>
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>
- <kbd>Delete</kbd>

This is not 'column based.' It only works because your IP addresses all line up.

Comment: What do you mean by "This is not 'column based.'"? Alt+Shift+Arrow switches to "column mode".

Comment: It doesn't respect tab-delineation as a column. It breaks them up into spaces so that each line in the selection has the same # of chars beyond the edge of the selections starting point.

Answer (score 2):

In regular expression mode, search for:

\t.*

And replace with

Nothing

Comment: Can you add a sentence or two to explain what this does?  Thanks.

Comment: Stack Exchange converts tabs to spaces while displaying, but even in edit mode, the example does not show any tabs.

Comment: Thanks this worked excellent in my case. Therefor upping!

Answer (score 0):

Delete everything after first column in Notepad++:

1. Selcect the 2nd column : <kbd>Alt</kbd> + Drag
2. For selecting rest columns: simply press <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>